# Is it possible to configure a DLL reference to always load the latest available version?

Tags: dll, assemblies, version, gac

Let's say I have a project A that references a 3rd-party library X. When I build v1.0 of A, I referenced v2.0 of X.

2 months later, v2.1 of X becomes available with some bug fixes that are important to us. I can't deploy it alone, however, because of the version mismatch.

I know about Assembly Binding Redirection which worked. I was wondering if there was a way to specify that a given reference is bound to the latest available version without having to add any configuration entries, etc.? (think of supporting clients using your DLLs that references other vendors' DLLs)

Comment: Anybody that updates an assembly with only bug fixes needs to change the [AssemblyFileVersion], not the [AssemblyVersion].  Changing the assembly version is a breaking change that requires that you explicitly re-reference the new assembly.  You can shoot your foot if you really want to by overwriting the reference DLL and setting its "Specific Version" property to False.

Comment: @HansPassant 3rd party X is made by an outside vendor and I have no control over the way they version their assemblies. Also, "Specific Version" applies to build time validation and not to run-time binding, which is what I'm after.